# Picking elements from multiple arrays

Tags: arrays, swift

How to get all the possible combinations of elements from multiple arrays in Swift?

Here is an example :

```
let myArray = [[2,3,4],
[1,2,3,4,5],
[1,2],
]
```

The count of `myArray` elements may vary, same goes for the arrays inside it.

The code should output an array by picking one element from each array at a time, seems basic but I can't see it now

Comment: Show us the code you’ve written so far.

Comment: I can't see how to approach this, but I am using some `for in` loops

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the ideas from https://stackoverflow.com/a/20049365/1187415, this can be
done in Swift as

```
// Append all elements of a2 to each element of a1
func combihelper(a1 : [[Int]], a2 : [Int]) -> [[Int]] {
    var result = [[Int]]()
    for elem1 in a1 {
        for elem2 in a2 {
            result.append(elem1 + [elem2])
        }
    }
    return result
}

func combinations(array : [[Int]]) -> [[Int]] {
    // Start with the "empty combination" , then successively
    // add combinations with each row of array:
    var result : [[Int]] = [[]]
    for row in array {
        result = combihelper(result, row)
    }
    return result
}
```

The last function can be written more Swiftly as

```
func combinations(array : [[Int]]) -> [[Int]] {
    return reduce(array, [[]]) { combihelper($0, $1) }
}
```

Example:

```
let myArray = [[1],
    [2,3,4],
    [5,6],
]
let result = combinations(myArray)
println(result)
// [[1, 2, 5], [1, 2, 6], [1, 3, 5], [1, 3, 6], [1, 4, 5], [1, 4, 6]]
```

(If your input is not restricted to integers, you can replace `Int` by `Any` in above
functions.)

---

Update for **Swift 3** and as a generic function, so that it can be
used with any element type:

```
func combihelper<T>(a1 : [[T]], a2 : [T]) -> [[T]] {
    var result = [[T]]()
    for elem1 in a1 {
        for elem2 in a2 {
            result.append(elem1 + [elem2])
        }
    }
    return result
}

func combinations<T>(of array: [[T]]) -> [[T]] {
    return array.reduce([[]]) { combihelper(a1: $0, a2: $1) }
}


let myArray = [[1],
               [2,3,4],
               [5,6],
]

let result = combinations(of: myArray)
print(result) // [[1, 2, 5], [1, 2, 6], [1, 3, 5], [1, 3, 6], [1, 4, 5], [1, 4, 6]]
```

Comment: Sorry, I missed the `reduce`.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted this as an extension, so here is a translation of Martin R's excellent answer as an extension on Collection and some tests that should cover it:

```
extension Collection where Element: Collection {
    typealias Output = [[Element.Element]]
    
    func combinations() -> Output {
        guard !isEmpty else { return [] }
        
        return reduce([[]], combinations)
    }
    
    private func combinations(_ c1: Output, _ c2: Element) -> Output {
        c1.reduce(into: Output()) { combinations, elem1 in
            c2.forEach { elem2 in
                combinations.append(elem1 + [elem2])
            }
        }
    }
}

final class CombinationsTests: XCTestCase {
    func assertCombinations(of a: [[Int]], expected: [[Int]], line: UInt = #line) {
        XCTAssertEqual(expected, a.combinations(), line: line)
    }
    
    func testCombinations() {
        assertCombinations(of: [], expected: [])
        assertCombinations(of: [[]], expected: [])
        assertCombinations(of: [[], []], expected: [])
        assertCombinations(of: [[1]], expected: [[1]])
        assertCombinations(of: [[1, 2]], expected: [[1], [2]])
        assertCombinations(of: [[1], [2]], expected: [[1, 2]])
        assertCombinations(of: [[1], [2], [3]], expected: [[1, 2, 3]])
        assertCombinations(of: [[1, 2], [3]], expected: [[1, 3], [2, 3]])
        assertCombinations(of: [[1, 2], [3, 4]], expected: [[1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 3], [2, 4]])
    }
}
```