# pairs of values in swift 3

Tags: arrays, swift, loops

```
var par = [[Double]]()

par.append(Array(stride(from: -1, through: 10, by: 1.0)))

//par[0] == [-1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0]

par.append(Array(stride(from: -10, through: 1, by: 1.0)))

//par[1] == [-10.0, -9.0, -8.0, -7.0, -6.0, -5.0, -4.0, -3.0, -2.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0]
//there could be more much more arrays in par…

//Total combinations, 144 in this case

var c: Int = 0
c = par[0].count
for i in 1 ..< par.count {
c *= par[i].count
}

for i in 0 ..< c {
//?
}
```

Hi! The question is what's the easiest way to make an array with values from par[0], par[1], ...? In this case 12x12: [-1.0, -10.0], [-1.0, -9.0], ..., [10.0, 1.0], but it could be 2x20, 2x10x50, 10x10x20x20…

Comment: So you want every possible tuple of n values out of n different arrays?

Comment: I think what you're looking for is the `cartesian product`. Try something like https://github.com/Oyvindkg/SwiftProductGenerator

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Picking elements from multiple arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25744861/picking-elements-from-multiple-arrays)