# Building combinations using recursion rather than using iteration

Tags: ios, objective-c, recursion, nsarray

I am trying to customise the combination method found in the solution given here: [Combinations of different NSArray objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20048824/combinations-of-different-nsarray-objects) so that it utilises recursion, instead of the solution given, which is using iteration. The reason why I am trying to customise this function is to increase the performance of this function as it starts slowing down significantly when the arrays start getting larger and there are many combinations to compute.

Any advice on how this could be done?

Comment: Just to check. Do you want the single values like in the linked question? ie. the first few "combinations" are just the separate values from each array not combined with anything.

Comment: Not necessarily. Anything with 2 to an arbitrary amount is what i would like. Max would be 4 combinations.

Comment: @Fogmeister, could you advise how this could be done?

Comment: Was trying to think of a way but not sure it's any better than iteration. Actually, I just thought of something. one sec...

Comment: Would it be faster if implemented?

Comment: Recursion is unlikely to be faster than iteration. You can use `dispatch_apply` to introduce concurrency but the amount of work done in each iteration is fairly trivial, so there may not be any advantage once you include the overhead associated with the dispatch - see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/concurrencyprogrammingguide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW23

Comment: Recursion is almost always slower and more resource intensive, yet often simpler to write. I remember one section of a Comp Sci class dedicated to algorithms to remove recursion. Recursion is often used as a learning tool in programming, but it's almost never the best solution for real world code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd have to combine iteration and recursion. If you want it to do a varying number of arrays then I came up with something like this...

First pass at an iterative method.

```
- (NSArray *)combineArrays:(NSArray *)arrays
{
    // arrays is an array of arrays of elements that you want to combine.

    NSMutableArray *combinations = [NSMutableArray array];

    for(NSArray *array in arrays) {
        NSMutableArray *temp = [NSMutableArray array];

        for (id element in array) {
            if (combinations.count == 0) {
                // the first level of the array is just all the elements from the first array
                [temp addObject:@[element]];
            } else {
                // copy each array in combinations for each new element and add new element to end
                for (NSArray *array in combinations) {
                    [temp addObject:[array arrayByAddingObject:element];
                }
            }
        }

        // save the current combinations
        combinations = temp;
    }

    return combinations;
}
```

I'm almost certain that the middle part can be recursed into a single method. Just working on that now.

```
- (NSArray *)combineArray:(NSArray *)combinations withArrays:(NSMutableArray *)arrays
{
    // if there are no arrays to combine then you are at the end of recursion so return combinations.
    if (!array || array.count == 0) {
        return combinations;
    }

    // to start with you "combine" the first array with an empty array
    if (!combinations) {
        combinations = @[@[]];
    }

    NSMutableArray *newCombinations = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSArray *array = [arrays firstObject];    

    for (id element in array) {
        for (NSArray combination in combinations) {
            [newCombinations addObject:[combination arrayByAddingObject:element];
        }
    }

    [arrays removeObjectAtIndex:0];

    return [self combineArray:newCombinations withArrays:arrays];
}
```

Something like this might work. It's no faster than iteration though.

Take a look at this answer [JavaScript - Generating combinations from n arrays with m elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15298912/javascript-generating-combinations-from-n-arrays-with-m-elements) which does what you want but in JavaScript. You still have to touch each element of each array once though.